# HTML form with zend fm

Tags: html, xml, zend-framework, forms

http://pastebin.com/xrzbVWse

So, I have an textarea input which has some spaces at the beginning. I press the submit button, it goes through the PHP and then echos the same stuff again into the input for correction. So, if i have had 3 spaces then i now have 2. and if I press the button again, im getting just 1. So on each button press, it deletes me one space. I dont trim it anywhere.

Why is that? A easy solution would be to att "\n" to xmlData but i'd like to know where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the problem is not with your code. It appears that this is how textarea input fields work, i.e. they ignore first empty line (have a look at, e.g. [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8627), [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/losing-empty-line-at-beginning-of-textarea) or [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/commits@wicket.apache.org/msg16662.html)) One possible workaround would be to add `&nbsp;` to the first empty line, rather than to have it completely empty, or add `\n` as you suggested.